# Cannot get src of image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a close button which is used to get an image `src` positioned just above it:

```html
<div class="col">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="/path/to/image2.gif">
    <br>
    <span class="img-remove">x</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.img-remove', function () {
    let _self = this;
    let img_src = $(this).closest('.img-thumbnail').attr("src");
    console.log('img_src', img_src);
});
```

However instead of `src` value I get this in console:

> img_src undefined

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: HI, you can use `$(this).closest('.col').find('.img-thumbnail').attr('src')`

Comment: @Swati Yes, this one works! Just wondering why mine did not work? shouldn't `closest` look upward `this` div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$(this).closest('.img-thumbnail')` to `$(this).siblings('.img-thumbnail')` will solve your issue

Example code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.img-remove', function () {
    let _self = this;
    let img_src = $(this).siblings('.img-thumbnail').attr("src");
    console.log('img_src', img_src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="/path/to/image2.gif">
    <br>
    <span class="img-remove">x</span>
</div>
```

---

### Explain:

`$(this)` is `span.img-remove`, `.closet()` will traversing up through its ancestors. But you need to find `img.img-thumbnail`, it's sibling of `$(this)` not ancestors. So you need to use `.siblings()` to find the sibling.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.img-remove', function() {
  let _self = this;
  let img_src = $(this).closest('.col').find('.img-thumbnail').attr("src");
  console.log('img_src', img_src);
});
```